# iphone xml parser as easy to use as the objective-c JSON framework

Tags: iphone, web-services, xml-parsing

basically im looking for something that will just turn xml into an nsdictionary hierarchy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey Nick, I wrote an XML to NSDicitonary converter you might find useful:

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/

Comment: +1 for my side , Helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Troy Brant's code improved:
https://github.com/Insert-Witty-Name/XML-to-NSDictionary

Answer (score 0):

On the iPhone, the way to do XML parsing is to use the [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, which takes a delegate (a.k.a. visitor) object of type [NSXMLParserDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSXMLParserDelegate) which gets invoked as different parts of the XML tree are visited. So, you can create a delegate that stores away the information into a dictionary. That said, most likely you won't care about everything in the XML  that you parse, which is exactly why these parsing mechanism exists; you can create  delegate that stores just the bits you want, which is faster and more memory efficient than adding a new dictionary entry for everything even if you never use it.

Comment: I 100 percent hear what you're saying but if I want to just use a quick and dirty xml parser for a small piece of xml, that I don't have to dive into, there isn't really much out there then? I guess this brings up another question which is: is JSON just much more elegant of a solution why should we have to reinvent the wheel each time we go to start parsing xml, from the outside looking in it seems like a waste of my time but, I also hear what you're saying in that hey just parse what you need and ignore the rest. if it's that much of a pain to parse XML is JSON becoming the new hawtness?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://theappleblog.com/2008/08/04/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/) is tutorial with sample code explaining parsing a XML with NSXMLParser and save it as a array of dictionaries and displaying it in a tableview.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my XML library for that, [it's here](http://codecruncher.wordpress.com).